# what class or id to find all products when scraping arcteryx website?

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape the arcteryx website so get a list of mens products into csv format. I am having trouble navigating the html on the website. More specifically, I am having issues loading all the products because I can't seem to find which class or id to use to extract all the products using find_all. Any tips would be very much appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get("https://arcteryx.com/ca/en/c/mens")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
products = soup.find_all**(id="content")**
print(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is dynamically retrieved from another endpoint you can find in network tab of browser. You can simplify request made but need to pick up a site identifier from the original url

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://arcteryx.com/ca/en/c/mens')
p = re.compile(r'ATTRACT_SITE_ID: "(.*?)"')
site_id = p.findall(r.text)[0]
params = (
('siteId', f'{site_id}'),
('zone0', 'CDP_Main_Product_Grid'),
('region', 'ca'),
('currency', 'CA_CAD'),
('fields', 'name,prices,images,alt_image,rating,review_count,gender,FSM_CategoryTitles,url,subname,shortdescription,FSM_Color,FSM_Color_With_Regions,FSM_Attrimages,color,baseColor,weight,size,new,toprated,revised'),
('language', 'en'),
('config_warehouse', 'VAN'),
('config_categorytree', 'WEBCAT'),
('config_gender', 'MALE,NEUTRAL'),
('config_country', 'ca'),
('overlay', 'true'),
('aid', 'undefined')
)

r = requests.get('https://attraqt.arcteryx.com/zones-ajax.aspx',  params=params).json()
products = [i['fields']['name']['value'][0] for i in r['zones'][0]['data']['results']]
```